# MVVM - Add a Existing User Control in Grid(XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-store-apps

I am developing a `Windows 8.1 apps`,

and i am following `MVVM` Pattern

I have a Grid in the Application

```
<Grid Name="g1">
```

in which in need to add a existing User Control.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="CaptureApp.UIComponents.PlayVideo"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CaptureApp.UIComponents"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <MediaElement Name="MediaPlay" >

        </MediaElement>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`Since View (XAML) is not allowed to know the Control.`

What will be the correct way to implement it??

Comment: I don't understand your issue. What's preventing you to declare your usercontrol inside the <Grid>?

Comment: Yea i can add the user control in the grid and handle it's visibility in mvvm but the user control will loaded along with the main application when the application starts.
whether i want to create a new instance of the user control on the click button.

Comment: Try to have a look at http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/. It should give you an idea on how to to it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

the wordpress blog in the comments uses a datatrigger, which isn't present in windows store apps.

if I understand your question correctly, you're trying to have a view within your grid that is conditionally loaded, so that when there is no data for the user control, it is not rendered in the grid?

you could accomplish this by using a

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding PropertyOnViewModel}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SomeContentTemplateSelector}" />. 

public class SomeContentTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public DataTemplate SomeTemplate {get;set;}

  protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    if (item is null)
      return null;
    return SomeTemplate;
  }
}
```

and then in a DataTemplate, have your UserControl as a child. This will display nothing when there is no Content bound to the ContentControl, and will otherwise display the supplied DataTemplate. You will need to have a property in the over-arching ViewModel that contains the content for this ContentControl, though, just fyi.

edit: if you're adding multiple items dynamically, then you will want an ObservableCollection<> property on your ViewModel, and use an ItemsControl instead of a ContentControl.